# Using <link>s with rel=next and rel=prev when pages are requested using POST

Tags: seo, pagination, post

On my site there is paginated content. Because there are many parameters for each page (a search with many filters), using GET for the parameters would produce quite long URLs. So I decided to use POST to request the paginated content.

Now I'd like to use `<link rel="prev" href="..."/>` and `<link rel="next" href="..."/>` tags for SEO.

Is this possible with POST requests, or do I have to create GET-URLs for the pages? Or maybe there is a totally different thing I could use?

Comment: For pagination it's best to use GET, pages retrieved with POST aren't bookmarkable and using back and forward links will ask the user to confirm resubmit each time, not really good practice.